# Beacon Detection using radius networks in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, ibeacon

I was able to create native applications in objective c and android using the respective sdks provided by the radius network for the detection of nearby beacons.Now I have a requirement of creating an application in titanium based on javascript  that detects nearby beacons based on radius network apis.I am fairly new to titanium development,so can anybody please let me know or rather provide any inputs on how to begin with it?Any help would be appreciated.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Titanium module available for detecting iBeacons & acting as iBeacons : [TiBeacons](https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons)

You can monitor a region using:

```
var TiBeacons = require('org.beuckman.tibeacons');
TiBeacons.startMonitoringForRegion({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", // Your UUID here
    identifier : "Test Region 1",
});

TiBeacons.startRangingForBeacons({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001", // Your UUID here
    identifier : "Test Region 2 (group-specific)",
    major: 1                                       // Your Major value
});

TiBeacons.startRangingForBeacons({
    uuid : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",  // Your UUID here
    identifier : "Test Region 3 (device-specific)",
    major: 1,                                       // Your Major value
    minor: 2                                        // Your Minor value
});

TiBeacons.addEventListener("enteredRegion", function(){
    alert('enteredRegion');
});

TiBeacons.addEventListener("exitedRegion", function(){
    alert('enteredRegion');
});

TiBeacons.addEventListener("determinedRegionState", function(){
    alert('enteredRegion');
});

TiBeacons.addEventListener("beaconRanges", function(event) {
   alert(event.beacons);
});

TiBeacons.addEventListener("beaconProximity", function(e){
   alert("beacon "+e.major+"/"+e.minor+" is now "+e.proximity);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Unfortunately the requirement is as such that I need to use the radius network apis for it.Do you know how to integrate it with radius networks?

Comment: @SumodhNair: I don't know why you need that, you can detect their beacons using the same code stated above. Let me check their API's

Comment: @SumodhNair: They don't have any titanium modules right now. So If you want to use their libraries itself, you need to convert them to titanium modules itself. Check : http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide and https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably be using TiBeacons for the time being then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Start from reading [Titanium documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/) and watching video tutorials: [Basic](http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/building-native-mobile-applications) and [Advanced](http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/advanced-titanium-mobile-development). If still not enough there is [list of training resources](http://training.appcelerator.com/training-resources)

If you need some code exampels [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) is very good source for that.

If you start getting familiar with Titanium SDK, you can try playing around with [Alloy MVC Framework](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Framework). Also [Tishadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/) is very usefull tool, which makes development much faster.

For BLE there are couple good modules on marketplace: [Bluetooth LE iOS Module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3834?restoreSearch=true#!overview) and [Bluetooth LE Android Module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/6611?restoreSearch=true#!overview). However, if you can code natively, it will be easier for you to write your own Titanium Module or play around with open sourced [TiBeacons](https://github.com/jbeuckm/TiBeacons)